# ReactJS: Why does an API populated HTML select field doesn't reset and can't be manipulated?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Dropdown option. The `projects` is loaded from redux-thunk:

```
 <select value={this.state.project} className="form-control input-sm" name="project_id" onChange={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)}>
                    <option value=''>Select a project...</option>
                    {this.props.projects.map(project => 
                        <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>{project.name}</option>)}
```

Initial component state:

```
this.state = {
        batchNo: '',
        project: '',
        category: '',
        transaction: ''
    };
```

When I try to `setState({ project: '' })` it does not work. **Also, I cannot choose value from the dropdown.**

Comment: If you can share a more complete example with something like jsfiddle, it would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: it should work, may be it is failing at some other place, check the console is it throwing any error, please provide more code. i dont think its a blank value prblm, check this `jsfiddle` its working properly with '' values: https://jsfiddle.net/dsapbtdm/

Comment: I tried with simple values i.e. declarative-ly specifying `<options>` items and it will work. Maybe it doesn't work if its loaded from an async call?

Comment: i dont think so, if u make the change in state variable, it will load the option dynamically, check this one initially contains no option, after click on button, its load the option dynamically `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/sf6v6v60/

Answer (score 0):

I know your problem. Seems that react check if there any value, that you pass, like

```
if (props.value) {

}
```

But when you pass an empty string as value, javascript converting it to the false, the same, also with `null`, `0`, etc..

So try to pass to your not 'falsable' function, for example `-1`, and onChange check that you have change your value, to the new one. And enjoy!

Comment: could you please expalin ur ans with this example its working properly with blank value `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/jabhu452/

Comment: I tried with simple values i.e. declarative-ly specifying <options> items and it will work. Maybe it doesn't work if its loaded from an async call / populated from redux props?

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo! my handler is using a the name `project_id` but my state is `project`.

```
handleFilterChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}`
```

Thank you guys for the help!